# Determine whether this is a subspace of $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $S$ be the following subset of the vector space $P_3$ of all real polynomials $p$ of degree at most 3:

$$S=\{p\in P_3\mid p(1)=0, p^\prime (1)=0\}$$

where $p^\prime$ is the derivative of $p$.

Determine whether $S$ is a subspace of $P_3$

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've tried to prove that it is not a subspace, but any example I've made proved me that I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need only prove that $S$ is closed, i.e.

1. For all $p,q\in S$, prove that $p+q\in S$
2. For all $p\in S$ and all $k\in\mathbb{R}$, prove that $kp\in S$

Comment: Just showing closure is insufficient. It is not the case that $p\in S$ and $(-1)p=-p\in S$ implies $p+(-p)=0\in S$ because this assumes that $S$ contains at least one element $p$.

Comment: It is obvious that $S$ is nonempty here.

Answer (score 0):

1. It contains the zero vector $p(x)=0$ because that satisfies both conditions.
2. It is closed under linear combinations because $(af+bg)(1)=af(1)+bg(1)=0+0=0$ and $(af+bg)'(1)=af'(1)+bg'(1)=0+0=0$.

What can you conclude?

Comment: I can see that it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition. Got it now. Thanx a lot.